# SQL string sorting

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to print  print the list of CITY from table STATION that ends at vowels in lexicographical order. Do not print duplicates.

I tried:

```
select 
  city 
from 
  station 
where 
  city like '%a' 
  or city like '%e' 
  or city like '%i' 
  or city like '%o' 
  or city like '%u' 
order by 
  city;
```

Comment: i tried:           select city from station where city like '%a' or city like '%e' or city like '%i' or city like '%o' or city like '%u' order by city ;

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: what is solution?????????????

Comment: It is always a good idea to quote the *full* error message your getting. This helps people to better understand your issue.

Comment: What test case is failing? Do you consider `y` as a vowel?

Comment: Try `select distinct` instead of `select`

Comment: If your data contains upper-case letters, you should compare with `lower(city) like '%a' ` etc.

Comment: thanks Egor.passes all the test cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql,string end with vowel in lexicographical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406037/sql-string-end-with-vowel-in-lexicographical-order)

Comment: QUE: Let |city| be the length of the city, write a query to print two lines:
1. First line is city1 and |city1| separated by space, where |city1| is the possible minimum value.
2. Second line is city2 and |city2| separated by space, where |city2|  is the possible maximum value.
If there are more than one possible cities print the lexicographical smallest.

Comment: I TRIED: select (select city||'    '||length(city) from station   where length(city)= (select min(length(city)) from station) order by city ;
select city||'    '||length(city) from station   where length(city)= (select max(length(city)) from station) order by city ;
BUT IT'S ERROR WHY ???plz tell me plz

Comment: This is just a repeat of your previous, heavily-downvoted question, right?

Comment: If you have a new question. Just create a new one. Also please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) otherwise you will keep getting negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solve all parts from your question.

As Egor said you need distinct

```
SELECT distinct city 
FROM station 
WHERE substr(city ,-1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' )
ORDER BY substr(city ,-1)
```

Instead of multiply `ORs` You could extract last char of the city.

Then you say want to sort for last letter. Also include the proper `ORDER BY`

And finally have you consider cities with accent vowel like `Perú` (I know is a country not a city), using my solution is easy to add those to the `IN` list.

```
WHERE substr(city ,-1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'á', 'í', 'é', 'ó', 'ú') )
```